# I'm struggling to find which is the right statistical test to use?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test

I have two variables: cell death and diet, but on the diet variable I have several groups that I want to compare. I was thinking of doing multiple Mann-Whitney tests, but that would be very time consuming. So I was wondering if doing a Kruskal-Wallis test would be similar. Any help on this?

[image]

I added one example of the data to help the discussion. Each group have multiple data points and the size samples are different. I want to compare each group with every other group.Thank you so much

Comment: From the tests you have mentioned I would guess that you are interested in [stochastic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance), or maybe you are using what I call [*Wilcoxon's heuristic*](https://galenseilis.github.io/posts/wilcoxons-heuristic/), but to avoid an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) I suggest you tell us more about the question(s) you want to answer with the data.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So I want to know if a certain type of diet (blue one) induces more cell death than the grey one. Also, I want to know, within the blue diet, which genotypes (X axis) induce changes in cell death results. So what I want to do is to compare all the genotypes between them. Usually what I do is to do comparisons of 2 genotypes using Mann-whitney, but I'm not sure if it is the most correct way. Also, They are independent from one another and I do not assume normality.

Comment: I'm not clear whether the two diets (gray and blue) are given to individuals with all genotypes (the "X axis" in your example, according to your comment). In your example there are two gray bars and 7 blue bars. If not all the genotypes get both diets, it might be impossible to distinguish diet effects from genotype effects. Please edit your question to (1) incorporate the information from your prior comment and (2) provide more detail about the total experimental design. Comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted, so it's best to provide this information by editing the question itself.